# changing the variable of function after defining the function in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have this function:

```
    $(function () {
            // declaration 
$("#thermogauge").ejLinearGauge({
                labelColor: "#8c8c8c", load: "loadGaugeTheme",
                height: 400, width: 250, drawLabels: "DrawLabel", drawCustomLabel: "DrawCustomLabel", enableAnimation: false,
                scales: [{
                    type: "thermometer", backgroundColor: "transparent", minimum: -10, maximum: 110, minorIntervalValue: 5, scaleBarSize: 20, position: { x: 50, y: 18 }, length: 200, border: { width: 0.5 },
                    showCustomLabels: true,
                    markerPointers: [{ opacity: 0 }],
                    barPointers: [{
                        width: 10, distanceFromScale: -0.5,
                        value: 0, backgroundColor: "#DB3738"
                    }],
                    labels: [{
                        placement: "near", font: { size: "10px", fontFamily: "Segoe UI", fontStyle: "Normal" }
                    }, {
                        placement: "far",
                        distanceFromScale: { x: 10 }
                    }],
                    ticks: [{
                        type: "majorinterval", height: 8, width: 1, color: "#8c8c8c", distanceFromScale: { y: -4 }
                    }, {
                        type: "minorinterval", height: 4, width: 1, color: "#8c8c8c", distanceFromScale: { y: -4 }
                    }, {
                        type: "majorinterval", placement: "far", height: 8, width: 1, color: "#8c8c8c", distanceFromScale: { y: -4 }
                    }, {
                        type: "minorinterval", placement: "far", height: 4, width: 1, color: "#8c8c8c", distanceFromScale: { y: -4 }
                    }],
                    customLabels: [{
                        value: "(° C)",
                        position: { x: 44, y: 70},
                        font: "bold 12px Segoe UI", color: "#666666"
                    }, {
                        value: "(° F)",
                        position: { x: 56, y: 70},
                        font: "bold 12px Segoe UI", color: "#666666"
                    },
                    {
                        position: { x: 51, y: 75},
                        font: "bold 13px Segoe UI",
                        color: "#666666"
                    }]
                }]
            });
        });
```

I want to change the value of 'value' variable after that function, like below:

```
$('#thermogauge').ejLinearGauge('value', 60);
```

but it doesn't work. I think it's reason is being the value in the 'barPointers' but I don't know how I can change it...
could you plz help me?

Comment: Does the plugin support changing the value, there's no magic way to do that, the plugin has to be coded to actually accept calls that change internal properties.

Comment: That's not a function declaration but a function call

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the different functions you have available [here](http://help.syncfusion.com/UG/JS_CR/ejLinearGauge.html), but it looks like you  need to do one of the following:

```
$('#thermogauge').data("ejLinearGauge").setBarPointerValue(0,0,30);
$('#thermogauge').data("ejLinearGauge").setIndicatorValue(0,0,30);
$('#thermogauge').data("ejLinearGauge").setPointerValue(0,0,30);
```